# why cron expression can not be execute correctly?

Tags: spring, cron

When I use `@Scheduled` annotation with cron expression "`0 0 0 * * ?`" in the program, the first time to execute it at `2017-10-07 00:00:00,000`, but the next time to execute it at `2017-10-07 23:59:59,895`. Why?

[image]

Comment: Becouse it was close enough to be considered as it fits the expression. Implementaion probably uses somehow Thread.Sleep(...) which is not guaranteed to be awaken at exact time. So the operating system awakes the thread a bit too early. If the library doesn't check this case, then your script will be executed earlier or much later. As you see it's allmost next day.

Comment: I read source code to find that task was added to DelayedWorkQueue,when executor take a task, it was parked for condition.awaitNanos(delay), delay time was computed from system.currentTimeMills add the result from expression, so when it was awaken, the time maybe not exactly. Thank you